# PosgreSQL fetch arrays as tuples instead of list using psycopg2

Tags: python, list, tuples, psycopg2

When fetching results from a database in `psycopg2`, array values will be returned as lists. For example, with a table `my_table` created with:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
    ('one', 1, ARRAY[1,2,3]),
    ('two', 2, ARRAY[2,3,4]),
    ('three', 3, ARRAY[3,4,5])
) s(eng, num, lst)
)
```

That looks like:

```
eng  |num|lst    |
-----|---|-------|
one  |  1|{1,2,3}|
two  |  2|{2,3,4}|
three|  3|{3,4,5}|
```

If the table is fetched using `psycopg2`:

```
from psycopg2 import connect
login = dict(
  host='localhost',
  dbname='my_db',
  user='postgres',
  password='****'
)

with connect(**login) as conn:
  cursor = conn.cursor()
  cursor.execute("SELECT eng,num,list FROM my_table")
  rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

The variable `rows` will look like:

```
[
    ('one', 1, [1, 2, 3]),
    ('two', 2, [2, 3, 4]),
    ('three', 3, [3, 4, 5])
]
```

Where the `lst` column is a Python `list`.

I wrote the following to convert any list columns to tuples, but I'm wondering if there's a way to tell the cursor to read SQL arrays as tuples instead of lists, and possibly speed up the process.

```
def force_list_columns_to_tuple(rows):
    list_col_indices = [
        index for index, value in enumerate(rows[0])
        if isinstance(value, list)
    ]

    if len(list_col_indices) > 0:
        for row_index in range(len(rows)):
            row = list(rows[row_index])
            for i in list_col_indices:
                row[i] = tuple(row[i])
            rows[row_index] = tuple(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I wrote the following to convert any list columns to tuples, but I'm wondering if there's a way to tell the cursor to read SQL arrays as tuples instead of lists

It's possible that defining your own psycopg2 [adapter function](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/advanced.html#type-casting-from-sql-to-python) or [adapter object](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/advanced.html#adapting-new-types) would override [the builtin adaptation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adaptation-of-python-values-to-sql-types) between python lists and postgres arrays, though I have a hard time seeing the value.